# What's complexity of this palindrome function?

Tags: palindrome

```
<?php

    function p($s){
    $count = strlen($s);
    $start = 0;
    $end = $count-1;
        $r = true;
        while($start<$end){ 
            if(!isChar($s[$start])){
                $start++;
            }
            elseif(!isChar($s[$end])){
                $end--;
            }else{
                if($s[$start] !== $s[$end]){
                    $r = false;
                    break;
                }
                $start++;
                $end--;
            }
        }
        return $r;
    }


    function isChar($char){
        $char = strtolower($char);
        if (preg_match('/[a-z]/', $char)) {
         return TRUE;
        }
    }


    print_r(p("23123123!!,,we2ew")); // return true
?>
```

Hi everyone, 
I wrote function, that checking if string is a palindrome. String can contain any characters, digits and symbols, But I need check within a-z chars

123ebc123 - false
,<>ebbe - true
123/.~!!aaa - true

Is this most efficient way to implement this function?

p.s. don't look at the isChar function implementation, imagine there just a func that return true or false if char is letter

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If we use Big Oh notation to represent time complexity of your algorithm it will be O(n)

Comment: There is a more efficient way to search this space, but it's a common homework question so you should be able to find this quite quickly using google...  As a hint, using regex for simple letter checking probably isn't the speediest approach ;-)